# how to solve second order differental equationwith variable coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE: ($y:(-1,1)→R, t↦ y(t)$ a function)
    $$y'' + t\cdot y'/(1-t) - y/(1-t) =0 $$

Is there any general method for solving this..? Because I only know how to solve 2nd order differential equations with constant rates.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-t)y''+ty'-y=0$$
An obvious particular solution is $y=c\:t$ . So, we replace $c$ by an unknown function $u(t)$

$y=tu$

$y'=tu'+u$

$y''=tu''+2u'$

$$(1-t)(tu''+2u')+t(tu'+u)-tu=0$$

$$(t-t^2)u''+(2-2t+t^2)u'=0$$
$v=u'$
$$(t-t^2)v'+(2-2t+t^2)v=0$$
This is a first order linear ODE. Solve it for $v(t)$ which gives $u'(t)$. Integrate for $u(t)$. And finally you find $y(t)=tu(t)$

Comment: so the key is to  observe an obvious solution and  replace the constant with an unknown function? is this a general method ? however thank you very much for your time, you helped me a lot!!

Comment: Infortunately it not always so easy. This trick works only for a few kind of ODEs. If it doesn't works, one have to look for other more complicated methods. By chance, it works in the present case, so why seaching something else ?

Comment: I 'm not complaining at all :) All I 'm saying is that, it would be great to have a method for the general type of 2nd order differential equations with variable coefficients and not seek for tricks every time.. But as you pointed out it's not that easy.. thank you again!!

Comment: Many linear second order ODE with non-constant coefficients have solutions which cannot be expressed on closed form. Some require special functions such as : Bessel functions, Hypergeometric functions and many other. So, one understand that a general method doesn't exist, but several methods depending on the kind of functions involved into the non-constant coefficients. Some examples of special functions and the related ODEs are mentioned in : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales